# Unity Vuforia Multiple Targets Video Autoplay Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have an issue here with Unity. I've tried to search the solution online, tested it, but doesn't work. Right now, I'm developing an AR application with Unity and Vuforia. I'm using multiple image targets with 3D objects and video.

The issue is that the video will autoplay without scanning the target yet. I've unticked the 'play on awake' but it will only show me a white quad (as I attached the video on the quad object).

I've also tried to add quad.Play() & quad.Stop() on DefaultTrackableEventHandler script as some of the people manage to get it work.

Here are the scripts:

```
/*==============================================================================
Copyright (c) 2017 PTC Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Copyright (c) 2010-2014 Qualcomm Connected Experiences, Inc.
All Rights Reserved.
Confidential and Proprietary - Protected under copyright and other laws.
==============================================================================*/

using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

/// <summary>
/// A custom handler that implements the ITrackableEventHandler interface.
///
/// Changes made to this file could be overwritten when upgrading the Vuforia version.
/// When implementing custom event handler behavior, consider inheriting from this class instead.
/// </summary>
public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{

    public UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer quad;

    #region PROTECTED_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    protected TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    protected TrackableBehaviour.Status m_PreviousStatus;
    protected TrackableBehaviour.Status m_NewStatus;

    #endregion // PROTECTED_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    #region UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            mTrackableBehaviour.UnregisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }

    #endregion // UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    #region PUBLIC_METHODS

    /// <summary>
    ///     Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
    ///     tracking state changes.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        m_PreviousStatus = previousStatus;
        m_NewStatus = newStatus;

        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
            OnTrackingFound();
        }
        else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED &&
                 newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
        else
        {
            // For combo of previousStatus=UNKNOWN + newStatus=UNKNOWN|NOT_FOUND
            // Vuforia is starting, but tracking has not been lost or found yet
            // Call OnTrackingLost() to hide the augmentations
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }

    #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS

    #region PROTECTED_METHODS

    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        quad.Play();
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Enable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = true;
    }


    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        quad.Stop();
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Disable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = false;
    }

    #endregion // PROTECTED_METHODS
}
```

Hope you guys can help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add code to play and pause video player in OnTrackingFound() and OnTrackingLost()respectively.

> For OnTrackingFound()

```
if (mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>() != null)
   {
            mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>().Play();
   }
```

> For OnTrackingLost()

```
if (mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>() != null)
    {
            mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>().Pause();
    }
```

> Complete script. Replace your script with this code.

```
using UnityEngine;

using Vuforia;

using UnityEngine.Video;      //added

/// <summary>

///     A custom handler that implements the ITrackableEventHandler interface.

/// </summary>

public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler

{

    #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    protected TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

    #endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    #region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    protected virtual void Start()

    {

        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();

        if (mTrackableBehaviour)

            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);

    }

    #endregion // UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    #region PUBLIC_METHODS

    /// <summary>

    ///     Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the

    ///     tracking state changes.

    /// </summary>

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(

        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,

        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)

    {

        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||

            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||

            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)

        {

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");

            OnTrackingFound();

        }

        else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED &&

                 newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE)

        {

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");

            OnTrackingLost();

        }

        else

        {

            // For combo of previousStatus=UNKNOWN + newStatus=UNKNOWN|NOT_FOUND

            // Vuforia is starting, but tracking has not been lost or found yet

            // Call OnTrackingLost() to hide the augmentations

            OnTrackingLost();

        }

    }

    #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS

    #region PRIVATE_METHODS

    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()

    {

        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);

        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)

            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders:

        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)

            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas':

        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)

            component.enabled = true;

        // added

        if (mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>() != null)

        {

            mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>().Play();

        }

    }



    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()

    {

        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);

        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Disable rendering:

        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)

            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable colliders:

        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)

            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable canvas':

        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)

            component.enabled = false;

        // added

        if (mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>() != null)

        {

            mTrackableBehaviour.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<VideoPlayer>().Pause();

        }

    }

    #endregion // PRIVATE_METHODS

}
```